# Flink: SessionWindowTimeGapExtractor - Compute the gap dynamically using data density

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a message coming from Kafka into flink and I would like to create an EventTimeSessionWindows.withDynamicGap() that is adapting over time considering the density of the data. To do this I have to create an enriched message that is holding my "Event" + "the gap" that I have to calculate dynamically.

The enriched message will then be: Tuple2<**Event**, **Long**>> where
**Event**: is a pojo that contains a CSV from kafka [tom, 53, 1.70, 18282822, ...] and
**Long**: is the gap parameter in millis [129293838]

Currently this part of my code is:

```
 DataStream<Tuple2<Event, Long>> enriched = stream 
                    .keyBy((Event ride) -> ride.CorrID)        
                    .map(new StatefulSessionCalculator());
```

Where `StatefulSessionCalculator()` enriches the message creating the Tuple2 describe above.

After this i have to take the calculated gap out using something like this:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<Event, Long>> result = enriched
                 .keyBy((...) -> ride.CorrID)
                 .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withDynamicGap(new DynamicSessionWindows())
```

My function **DynamicSessionWindows()** should do the job feeding back to flink the long but I don't understand how. This would just be a class that extends SessionWindowTimeGapExtractor<Tuple2<MyEvent, Long>> and returns the gap from the extract() method.

I have the theory but I would need an example of how to do it.

If anyone can help me with this by putting down some code, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, I found how to do it. It was a simple question but beeing new to JAVA and FLINK made me struggle a bit. I have also created a KeySelector

```
 WindowedStream<Tuple2<Event, Long>, String, TimeWindow> result = enriched
                .keyBy(new MyKeySelector())
                .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withDynamicGap(new DynamicSessionWindows()));
```

And my DynamicSessionWindows() is this one:

```
    public class DynamicSessionWindows implements SessionWindowTimeGapExtractor<Tuple2<Event, Long>> {
    
            @Override
            public long extract(Tuple2<Event, Long> value){
                return value.f1;
            }
    
    }
```